# How to change container configuration without Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I'v created a `Dockerfile`, with all initial configuration I needed, including `EXPOSE` and `CMD` instructions. Then, I've built a container and created an image from it. Then, I've started a new container from that image, and made some changes in it. Then, made a new commit and pushed my new image to the repo.

Now I want to change the image by adding new `EXPOSE` instructions to it. Obviously, I don't want to start again with a `Dockerfile`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXPOSE` instruction is equivalent to `docker commit -run '{"PortSpecs": ["<port>", "<port2>"]}'`.  If you want to change the `EXPOSE`, just run the latter at the command line ([ref](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/reference/builder/#expose)).